# nginx - log SSL handshake failures

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm running an nginx server with SSL enabled.

My protocol / cipher settings are fairly secure, and I've checked them at ssllabs.com, but --

-- since this is a web service which is called by http clients that I have no control over, I have concerns about compatibility.

To the point:

Is there a way to log SSL handshake failures as they happen (if they happen) in my nginx logs?

For example, I've got SSLv3 disabled, and if I try to "curl -3" (forcing SSlv3) to my server, then I get this:

> - NSS error -12286 (SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP)
> - Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
> - Closing connection 0 curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).

I would like to log this type of error in server logs too, with the default nginx settings, there is nothing.

Enabling "debug" log level for the error log does what I want, will log SSL handshake errors -- but unfortunately it also logs too much other stuff, making the log too bloated, drowning out other potentially useful info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `info` log level.

Comment: Here's an example of what to expect in error log. `2019/06/27 15:04:24 [info] 19422#0: *51804 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094415:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate expired:SSL alert number 45) while SSL handshaking, client: 50.108.221.155, server: 0.0.0.0:443`