# Nginx metrics, SSL negotiation time metrics

Tags: ssl, nginx, metrics

I am trying find if there is any module or way to get metrics from NGINX and especially about SSL connection (Negotiation time etc.)

I ve searched also in access log but with no luck.

I ve also search to do that using somehow tcpdump to packet analysis

Is there anyway to do that from serve side to take those metrics?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Have you done any internet searches to research this? I googled for "nginx metrics" and found links that look like information that would be of help for this question. Please take a look at some of these and then update your question with what you looked at and what you're still hoping for help with or answer and close your question with the info that solved it.

Comment: Yes, I ve done some research but not fit to me. Please could share some links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will answer your question but I hope that it can help...

Here are two web pages that I found that provide general information on Nginx metrics (including modules for metrics):

1. [How to Monitor Nginx: The Essential Guide](https://www.scalyr.com/community/guides/how-to-monitor-nginx-the-essential-guide).
2. [An In-Depth Guide to Nginx Metrics](https://www.scalyr.com/community/guides/an-in-depth-guide-to-nginx-metrics).

The first of these includes a section on "SSL Certificate expiration". But monitoring for SSL expiration dates and/or alerts for that seems limited in regards to the SSL connection metrics portion of your question.

On my searching for more SSL specific metric information for Nginx, I came across [Module ngx_http_status_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_status_module.html). In the "SSL" subsection of the "Data" section of the page, I found mention of the following SSL statistics:

> - handshakes
>     The total number of successful SSL handshakes.
> - handshakes_failed
>     The total number of failed SSL handshakes.
> - session_reuses
>     The total number of session reuses during SSL handshake.

I also found a paper [Nginx SSL Performance](https://www.nginx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/NGINX-SSL-Performance.pdf) that looked interesting to me in regards to Nginx SSL metrics albeit more from the perspective of a basis for what kinds of performance one can expect. It does however point out using `openssl speed` to gather metrics. Of course this presumes that Nginx was built with OpenSSL as the SSL library.

That leads me to the SSL library that your Nginx is built with. Whether it's OpenSSL or something else, it should have support for logging details. Here's a StackOverflow Q & A that's related to logging SSL details: [nginx - log SSL handshake failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934956/nginx-log-ssl-handshake-failures). While it doesn't sound like logs were the way you primarily wanted to get metrics from, it does seem like another resource even if you have to write some code to analyze them more conveniently.

Along the lines of analysis, I found the web page [Debugging SSL Problems](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DebuggingSSLProblems). While it's written with Apache's web server in mind, it does look like it would have helpful suggestions for analyzing and debugging Nginx SSL operations too.

As far as ways that perhaps you can get better answer(s), perhaps asking on the [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) Q & A site would help. You'll need to figure out how best to do that however as I recall seeing cross-posting being discouraged. Perhaps this Q & A can just be moved over to there since that seems like a more appropriate site for this. I don't know though.

Incidentally, I've written Nginx modules before and this question got more interesting to me as I dug into answering it.